# State variables and state space models

Tags: thermodynamics

If I want to model a system: For example a very simpley spring/mass system: What are the so called "state-variables"? Just position and velocity? Or acceleration (too)? When is meant by „in this model, pressure and temperature is a state“? And is there a difference between transfering a differential equation higher order into an ODE and "state-space" form? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The state space representation of a physical model typically transforms a set of high order differential equations into a set of 1st order differential equations that can be written in the algebra of matrices. The state variables an be chosen to be almost any combination of the physical variables since the state space realization is not unique and dependent on the model structure one choses. But it's most often convenient to chose the variables as the independent physical variables such as the example you mentioned. In the simple 2nd order harmonic oscillator position and velocity serve as the state variables. The acceleration does not, but it is present in the equations as the derivative of velocity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!! So the state-varaiables are not given by the system? In the simple mass-spring example: What would there be alternative state-variables?

Comment: @lars111 best way to understand this is to read about canonical forms. I will try to find an example tonight I can pint you to